# SMS Gateway setup from localhost server

Tags: php, mysql, sms-gateway

I have a server computer with `Windows OS` and `MySql` database installed.It contains my PHP program which has SMS sending feature, runs through ZEND Server and Apache. The server computer is connected to other client computer by networking. So client uses Internet Explorer to use the PHP program.

The server has constant Internet but the clients doesn't. The thing is SMS only  gets delivered if the client computer also has active Internet connection. Means whoever is using the program from main server the client has to have the internet connection, no matter if the server has Internet or not.

I don't want to share the internet connection to the clients but want them to able to send SMS through the program. I want something like if the server has the Internet then if anyone from client server is requesting to send SMS then the program will use the Internet from server and sen the SMS.

Is there any coding or solutions for doing that?

Comment: yes. there are solutions.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that?

Comment: in a nutshell. end user connects to webserver, sends an sms. sms enters queue. server also has a script running that monitors the queue, and sends out new messages as they arrive.

Comment: Here I don't want to provide Internet to the end user. Here my end users are the client computer connected to the local server. So how they will reach the webserver directly.

Comment: If I need to modify or write some new code at the place where the SMS api I have given or anywhere else then please tell me.

Comment: ? you just said the user connects via internet explorer. which means they access your php script via the webserver. thats what i meant.  yes you will need to modify probably everything by the sounds of it - but i've given you the gist of it.